# How to get name of the current route?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I need to get my current route name. I use `GlobalKey` to create `navigatorSevice` instead `Navigator.of(context)` in every page. So I create `navKey`:

```dart
class Keys {
    static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
}
```

And when I want to redirect to another page, I write `Keys.navKey.currentState.pushNamed()` or `pushReplacementNamed` or some another methods.

I want to know my current route in Interceptor, where I don't have a context.

Comment: Can you try `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name`

Comment: @IbrahimKarahan I don't want use context, because I don't have access to context inside Interceptor and I use Global Key yo navigate between pages.

Comment: @AndrewKovalchuk Have you found an answer to this question?

Comment: @Shravya no, unfortunately, I didn't find.

Answer (score 0):

You already have access to BuildContext from `GlobalKey<NavigatorState>()`.

Here - `navKey.currentContext`, plug it in like this - `ModalRoute.of(navKey.currentContext).settings.name`.

But this would fail, i'd recommend making the `navKey` property a getter. You can do this..

```dart
final App = Helper.I;

class Helper {
    static Helpers get I => Helpers._();

    Helpers._();

    GlobalKey<NavigatorState> get navKey => GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
    
    BuildContext get context => navKey.currentContext;

    double get height => MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    double get width => MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
}
```

This way, you always have access to BuildContext anywhere in you app (even in your business logic).

**Usage** - `App.context` or `App.width` (for device width)

Comment: Always return null, when get current path route name `ModalRoute.of(navKey.currentContext).settings.name` on class not Widget, for example Interceptor.

Comment: Did you add 'navKey' to the MaterialApp widget? Like this --- ```MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    navigatorKey: App.navKey,
)```. Adding this param binds routing. So performing `ModalRoute.of(navKey.currentContext).settings.name` should work

Comment: Yes, I add navKey in `MaterialApp`, but `ModalRoute` get route name, work only on page with route context, otherwise not work.

Comment: Alright probably a deprecation. This was working last i checked

Comment: Check out this package - https://pub.dev/packages/navigation_history_observer. Usage is simple just add it as an observer to MaterialApp and that's all.

Comment: To get current route anywhere without context, use as - ```String get currentRoute => NavigationHistoryObserver().top.settings.name;``` Use this if you don't mind adding a third party package just to get current route. I use this because i also use the AutoRoute Package